# Regex expression help to allow complete digits or with 3 special characters followed by 4 digits in comma separated without spaces

Tags: regex, numeric, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Looking for some help on regex expression for below use case.

My input field should allow only comma separated values of either just digits, or a sequence of special characters (`*`) followed by digits. It should able to allow below combinations:

```
1234,***1234,3456
***1234,***3456,12345567
1234,3456
***1234,***3456
```

The digits only case can have max 10 digits. The case with special characters and digits should have 3 asterisks followed by 4 digits.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Do you mean that each item in the comma separated list is either a number of up to 10 digits, or `***` followed by a number of 4 digits?

Comment: Yes Peter. it should allow either  digits upto 10 and  *** followed by 4 digits. 
The use will enter only digits or *** pattern or combination as listed in the above examples.

i have tried this  ^([*]{3}?\d{4}|\d{10}) but not sure how can i make comma separated and this will cover all scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This validates a string of comma separated items, where each item is either a number of up to 10 digits, or three `*` followed by a 4 digit number:

```
/^(?:\d{1,10}|\*{3}\d{4})(?:,(?:\d{1,10}|\*{3}\d{4}))*$/
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start of string
- `(?:` - non capture group start

  - `\d{1,10}` - 1 to 10 digits
  - `|` - logical OR
  - `\*{3}\d{4}` - three `*` followed by 4 digits
- `)` - non capture group end
- `(?:` - non capture group start

  - `,(?:\d{1,10}|\*{3}\d{4})` - a comma, followed by same ORed pattern as above
- `)*` - non capture group end, whole group has zero to many repetitions
- `$` - anchor at end of string

Comment: Thank you for nice explanation , will try and get back to you

Comment: @Jagadish Kumar: Does this fit your needs? Any questions?

Comment: @ Peter , it working as expected . Thank you for your help